# Blue color appear when click or use track wheel to click on button field

Tags: blackberry, focus

This blue color appear when click on buttonfield because I `setChangeListener()`. If I override `navigationClick()`, then work fine. However, it got problem on `TouchEvent`.

This is the button calling.

```
newsbtn = new Custom_ButtonField(news, newsactive, newsactive);
        newsbtn.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                Main.getUiApplication().pushScreen(
                        new Menu_PopupMenu(position));
            }
        });
        add(newsbtn);
```

This is the button declaration.

```
public class Custom_ButtonField extends ButtonField {
Bitmap mNormal;
Bitmap mFocused;
Bitmap mActive;

int mWidth;
int mHeight;

private int color = -1;
String text;

public Custom_ButtonField(Bitmap normal, Bitmap focused, Bitmap active) {
    super(CONSUME_CLICK | Field.FOCUSABLE | Field.FIELD_HCENTER
            | Field.FIELD_VCENTER);
    mNormal = normal;
    mFocused = focused;
    mActive = active;
    mWidth = mNormal.getWidth();
    mHeight = mNormal.getHeight();
    setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    setBorder(VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE,
            BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
}

public Custom_ButtonField(String text, Bitmap normal, Bitmap focused,
        Bitmap active, int color) {
    super(CONSUME_CLICK | Field.FOCUSABLE | Field.FIELD_HCENTER
            | Field.FIELD_VCENTER);
    this.color = color;
    mNormal = normal;
    mFocused = focused;
    mActive = active;
    mWidth = mNormal.getWidth();
    mHeight = mNormal.getHeight();
    setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    setBorder(VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE,
            BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    this.text = text;
}

public Custom_ButtonField(String text, Bitmap normal, Bitmap focused,
        Bitmap active, int color, long style) {
    super(style);
    this.color = color;
    mNormal = normal;
    mFocused = focused;
    mActive = active;
    mWidth = mNormal.getWidth();
    mHeight = mNormal.getHeight();
    setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    setBorder(VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE,
            BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    this.text = text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
    invalidate();
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setColor(int color) {
    this.color = color;
}

protected void onFocus(int direction) {
    super.onFocus(direction);
    color = 0x540604;
    this.invalidate();
}

protected void onUnfocus() {
    super.onUnfocus();
    color = Color.WHITE;
    this.invalidate();
}

protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    int fontcontent;
    if (Display.getWidth() > 480)
        fontcontent = 28;
    else if (Display.getWidth() < 481 && Display.getWidth() > 320)
        fontcontent = 23;
    else
        fontcontent = 18;

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    switch (getVisualState()) {
    case VISUAL_STATE_NORMAL:
        bitmap = mNormal;
        break;
    case VISUAL_STATE_FOCUS:
        bitmap = mFocused;
        break;
    case VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE:
        bitmap = mActive;
        break;
    default:
        bitmap = mNormal;
    }
    setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(bitmap));
    graphics.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN, fontcontent));
    graphics.setColor(color);
    graphics.drawText(text, (mNormal.getWidth() - Font.getDefault()
            .getAdvance(text)) / 2, ((mNormal.getHeight() - Font
            .getDefault().getHeight()) / 2) + 10, DrawStyle.HCENTER
            | DrawStyle.VCENTER);
}

public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return mWidth;
}

public int getPreferredHeight() {
    return mHeight;
}

protected void layout(int width, int height) {
    setExtent(mWidth, mHeight);
}
}
```

Even i override `drawFocus(){//nothing here}`, it still appeared blue color.

[Here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/715/focusing.png/) is the image when button is focusing.

[Here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/816/clicking.png/) is the image when clicking.

Comment: create two images. one for normal and one for mouse over

Comment: You don't need to set background on paint method. You can do it in constructor. Use this method for that, http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#setBackground%28int,%20net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.Background%29. You can pass the desired visual state and bitmap on that method.

Comment: previously is `drawbitmap()` but got problem, gray color appeared

Comment: @Signare I not understand, I already got two images, for mouse over, I will use back active state's image.

Comment: @Rupak I did this because I need to change the background image base on visual state.

Comment: Read my comment again. You can set background image depending on visual state using setBackground(visualState, backgroundInstance).

Comment: Then each constructor I need to set 3 background for different visual state

Comment: Alan, see my answer to your other question about button focus, and clicking.  I suggest starting with the `BitmapButtonField` from the blackberry Advanced UI Samples project.

Comment: @AlanLai, yes. You need to set different background instance for different visual state. Check this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11099436/431639.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the constructor.

```
public Custom_ButtonField(String text, Bitmap normal, Bitmap focused,
        Bitmap active, int color, long style) {
    super(style);
    this.color = color;
    this.text = text;
    mNormal = normal;
    mFocused = focused;
    mActive = active;
    mWidth = mNormal.getWidth();
    mHeight = mNormal.getHeight();
    setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    setBorder(VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE,
            BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    setBackground(VISUAL_STATE_NORMAL,
            BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(normal));
    setBackground(VISUAL_STATE_FOCUS,
            BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(focused));
    setBackground(VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE,
            BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(active));
}
```